# Trying to access jquery class for action but cannot

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access a jQuery class so that I can download my HTML table data into a text format. However, I have one column that is a selector with options and not just input. The table is dynamically generated. I know how to get that value, but I am having trouble with using the right logic. Right now my select box looks like this:

```
tbl +='<td ><select id="status" name="status" class="status" data id="'+row_id+'">';
                    tbl += '<option' + (val['IncludeThis'] == "yes" ? ' selected' : '') + '>yes</option>';
                    tbl += '<option' + (val['IncludeThis'] == "no" ? ' selected' : '') + '>no</option>';
tbl += '</select></td>';
```

Here is the jquery part where I am trying to get just the select values in addition to other values

```
$('tbody tr').each(function (idx, elem)
{
var elemText = [];
$(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
{
  const el = $(childElem);
  if ($(childElem).hasClass("status"))
  {
      elemtext.push(el.find('option:selected').text());
  }
  else {
  elemText.push($(childElem).text());
  }
});
```

However, the .hasClass hasn't been working nor has .is. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have one `<select>` in each row?? .. and did you checked about `childElem` .. And id should be unique so don't use same id for more than one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(childElem) is td itself, so hasClass checks whether td has any class with the name status or not. To find whether select box has any class status or not, You can try something like:

```
if ($(childElem).find('select').length > 0 && $(childElem).find('select').hasClass("status")) {
```

or

```
if ($(childElem).find('.status').length > 0) {
```

Also the syntax that you have provided have some issues.

1) There should not be any gap between **data id** in select box. It results in the select box having two ids.

2)

```
if ($(childElem).hasClass("status"))
  {
      elemtext.push(el.find('option:selected').text());
  }
```

No such variable as **elemtext** has been defined. You have defined **elemText**

3) If you have select boxes in more rows than id="status" cannot be assigned to each one of them.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! Can you explain the .length? Why does it have to be validated first if select options exist?

Comment: I assumed you don't have select box in all the rows, so by using length we are first checking whether select box exists in the row, if it exists then we are checking whether it has any class status. If you have select box inside td of every row then you can skip that condition.